# Mapping a global variable from a shared library with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

I'd like to map an int value `pbs_errno` declared as a global in the library `libtorque.so` using ctypes.

Currently I can load the library like so:

```
from ctypes import *
libtorque = CDLL("libtorque.so")
```

and have successfully mapped a bunch of the functions. However, for error checking purposes many of them set the `pbs_errno` variable so I need access to that as well. However if I try to access it I get:

```
>>> pytorque.libtorque.pbs_errno
<_FuncPtr object at 0x9fc690>
```

Of course, it's not a function pointer and attempting to call it results in a seg fault.

It's declared as `int pbs_errno;` in the main header and `extern int pbs_errno;` in the API header files.

Objdump shows the symbol as:

```
00000000001294f8 g    DO .bss   0000000000000004  Base        pbs_errno
```

Comment: John's answer is correct. Setting the restype only changes the return type of the function, AFAICT. If I actually tried to call pbs_errno as a function it resulted in a segfault.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's a section in the ctypes docs about accessing values exported in dlls:

http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls

e.g.

```
def pbs_errno():
    return c_int.in_dll(libtorque, "pbs_errno")
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I missed that section when using the docs. It's a big manual with a ton of varying content, easy to glance over and not notice :/