# Why does Python segfault when attempting to call environ using ctypes on libc?

Tags: python, linux, ctypes

Tested this both on Ubuntu and ArchLinux, I get

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
libc.environ()
Segmentation fault
```

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If i read the manpage correctly, `environ` is a `char**`, not a function.
If you want to get the environ var, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544173/mapping-a-global-variable-from-a-shared-library-with-ctypes), you could do:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
environ = c_char_p.in_dll(libc, 'environ')
```

But it return 'c_void_p(None)' for me, not sure why this happening (i know that i've declared as a `char *` only, but since it is returning None, their is nothing to dereference).

Anyway, you still have the "python" way:

```
import os
print os.environ
```

Or, if you search for a specific string in the environ using ctypes, for some function, you need to redefined the default restype:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = CDLL('libc.so.6')
getenv = libc.getenv
getenv.restype = c_char_p
print getenv('HOME')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could print C environ using `ctypes` on Ubuntu:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import ctypes

libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
environ = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p).in_dll(libc, 'environ')
for envvar in iter(iter(environ).next, None):
    print envvar
```

#### Output

```
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME=.project
SESSION=ubuntu
...
```