# How to export a C array to Python

Tags: python, c, arrays, ctypes

I have a file.cc that contains an array of doubles values, as seen here:

```
double values[][4] = {
  { 0.1234, +0.5678, 0.1222, 0.9683 },
  { 0.1631, +0.4678, 0.2122, 0.6643 },
  { 0.1332, +0.5678, 0.1322, 0.1683 },
  { 0.1636, +0.7678, 0.7122, 0.6283 }
  ... continue
}
```

How can I export these values to a Python list?

I cannot touch these files because they belong to an external library, subject to modification. Exactly, I want to be able to update the library without affecting my code.

Comment: Depends on the application: is this just a one-off thing where you need to move those numbers over to Python and keep them there, or do you need to access them from running C code, etc.  Just converting the text from C to Python should be trivial with a little Python script. Accessing them at runtime is another can or worms.

Comment: This `file.cc` should be some kind of C library to be used by a python program or an independent program? In case A you could check for `ctypes`, `cython` or write a small python C extension; in the second case you simply have to use some kind of IPC(exactly as if the python program was a different C program).

Comment: I cannot touch these files because they belong to an external library, subject to modification. Exactly, I want to be able to update the library without affecting the rest of my code.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty much answered in [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544173/mapping-a-global-variable-from-a-shared-library-with-ctypes).

But I will add a bit here.  You need to define a type then use the [`in_dll`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html?highlight=in_dll#ctypes._CData.in_dll) method.

From your example I made a so with those values in `values`.  I hope you have an idea how big it is or can find out from other vars in the library, otherwise this is a seg fault waiting to happen.

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL('so.so')
da = ctypes.c_double*4*4
da.in_dll(lib, "values")[0][0]
# 0.1234
da.in_dll(lib, "values")[0][1]
# 0.5678
da.in_dll(lib, "values")[0][2]
# 0.1222
```

From here I would just loop over them reading into a list.

Comment: Good to hear.  Unless a better answer appears you should accept the answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a temporary file? Put the matrix in it by C and read them by python.

In file.cc, write a function to save the matrix to a file.

```
int save_to_file(double matrix[][4],int row) {
    int i,j;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("tmp","w");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
            fprintf(fp,"%f",matrix[i][j]);
            if(j==3)
                fprintf(fp,"\n",matrix[i][j]);
            else
                fprintf(fp," ",matrix[i][j]);
        }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

and read them by a Python script like this:

```
tmp=open('tmp')
L = []
for line in tmp:
    newline = []
    t = line.split(' ')
    for string in t:
        newline.append(float(string))
    L.append(newline)
tmp.close()

for row in L:
    for number in row:
        print "%.4f" %number
    print " "
```

Comment: It could work, however I would like to do something more automatic with ctypes. I tried to use h2xml.py and xml2py.py but the last one doesn't seem to support that the array be initialized. It returns with "Cannot initialize ArrayType" error.