# Provide external definition of function with ctypes to a C/C++ library

Tags: c++, python, c, ctypes

I have a simple library that uses a function
hello_printf(const char *format, ...) in one of its API. While using
this library in C, I point the function pointer of hello_printf to
printf in the external application using the library and code works seamlessly.

hello_printf is not the API but is used in the implementation of one
of the API's. The reason for this is that I want external application
using the library to provide implementation of printf (external binding).

Now I want to use this library in python and I am using ctypes to call the API's but I am unable to find a way to find the provide external binding of function with ctypes. 
i.e. point hello_printf() to printf of libc such that "hello_printf = libc.printf ".

Comment: This is pretty much covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513708/how-to-export-a-c-array-to-python/16525801#16525801 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544173/mapping-a-global-variable-from-a-shared-library-with-ctypes , mentioned for completeness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `in_dll` method of ctypes data types.

C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int (*hello_printf)(const char *format, ...) = NULL;

int test(const char *str, int n) {
    if (hello_printf == NULL)
        return -1;
    hello_printf(str, n);
    return 0;
}
```

ctypes:

```
from ctypes import *

cglobals = CDLL(None)
lib = CDLL("./lib.so")

hello_printf = c_void_p.in_dll(lib, "hello_printf")
hello_printf.value = cast(cglobals.printf, c_void_p).value

>>> lib.test("spam %d\n", 1)
spam 1
0
```

Comment: Thanks. The solution works. Much appreciated. 

There is just one small issue with this solution. The hello_printf function gets resolved for the "lib.so" and works perfect. In my case, lib.so also opens another dynamic library via dlopen i.e. lib_runtime.so which also use hello_printf. Is there any way to expose the new functions to the other library that is being called from with the lib.so and not from python ctypes.

Comment: Do you mean something like passing the flag `RTLD_GLOBAL` to `dlopen`, i.e. `lib = CDLL('./lib.so', RTLD_GLOBAL)`? The default is `RTLD_LOCAL` on Linux.

Comment: Thanks much. You are right. I was just using the default mode hence it wasn't getting resolved for other libs. It works perfect. Thanks again for your help.